How do I reject requests based on IP in hyper service with a tower middleware for a warp server?
I have a warp server and I want to reject requests to certain endpoints that come from a certain IP (in this case anything that is not localhost). I make use of tower for rate limiting & timeouts. I can create make_service_fn to filter out the IP but I can't use my routes or tower middlewares. Is there a way to combine them?
I've tried this SO post but it only takes 1 handler instead of many.
Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
hyper-util = { version = "0.1.3", features = ["service", "server", "http1"] }
tokio = { version = "1.37.0", features = ["macros", "rt-multi-thread"] }
tower = { version = "0.4.13", features = ["limit", "timeout", "make", "buffer"] }
warp = "0.3.7"

[dev-dependencies]
local-ip-address = "0.6.1"
reqwest = { version = "0.12.4", features = ["blocking"] }

main.rs
use std::{net::SocketAddr, time::Duration};

use hyper_util::service::TowerToHyperService;
use tower::{buffer::BufferLayer, limit::RateLimitLayer, timeout::TimeoutLayer};
use warp::Filter;


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let any = warp::path!("any")
        .and(warp::filters::addr::remote())
        .map(|addr: Option<SocketAddr>| format!("remote address = {:?}", addr));

    let local = warp::path!("local")
        .map(|| "Welcome Local");

    let routes = warp::get().and(any.or(local));

    let server = warp::service(routes);

    let service = tower::ServiceBuilder::new()
        .layer(BufferLayer::new(1)) // Workaround for https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/discussions/877
        .layer(TimeoutLayer::new(Duration::from_secs(5)))
        .layer(RateLimitLayer::new(10, Duration::from_secs(1)))
        .service(server);
    let service = tower::make::Shared::new(service);

    const PROTECHTED_LOCAL_PATHS: [&str; 1] = ["/local"];

    let svc =
        warp::hyper::service::make_service_fn(|socket: &warp::hyper::server::conn::AddrStream| {
            let remote_addr = socket.remote_addr();
            async move {
                Ok::<_, std::convert::Infallible>(warp::hyper::service::service_fn(
                    move |req: warp::hyper::Request<warp::hyper::Body>| async move {
                        if !remote_addr.ip().is_loopback()
                            && PROTECHTED_LOCAL_PATHS.contains(&req.uri().to_string().as_str())
                        {
                            let mut r = warp::hyper::Response::new(warp::hyper::Body::from(
                                "FORBIDDEN".to_string(),
                            ));
                            *r.status_mut() = warp::hyper::StatusCode::FORBIDDEN;

                            return Ok::<_, std::convert::Infallible>(r);
                        }

                        Ok::<_, std::convert::Infallible>(
                            // This works
                            // warp::hyper::Response::new(warp::hyper::Body::from(format!("Hello, {}!", remote_addr)))

                            // how do I use or call tower here ??????
                            TowerToHyperService::new(service)
                        )
                    },
                ))
            }
        });

    let addr = ([0, 0, 0, 0], 8080).into();
    if let Err(e) = warp::hyper::Server::try_bind(&addr)
        .expect("Shepherd server should've bind")
        .serve(svc)
        .await
    {
        eprintln!("ERROR: {e:#?}");
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use local_ip_address::local_ip;

    #[test]
    fn test_local() {
        let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new();
        let res = client
            .get("http://localhost:8080/local".to_string())
            .send()
            .expect("failed to send");
        assert_eq!(reqwest::StatusCode::OK, res.status());

        let bytes = res.bytes().expect("bytes");
        let res = String::from_utf8_lossy(bytes.as_ref());
        assert_eq!("Welcome Local", res);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_remote() {
        let my_local_ip = local_ip().expect("local ip not found");
        let client = reqwest::blocking::Client::new();

        let res = client
            .get(format!("http://{my_local_ip}:8080/local"))
            .send()
            .expect("failed to send");
        assert_eq!(reqwest::StatusCode::FORBIDDEN, res.status());

        let bytes = res.bytes().expect("bytes");
        let res = String::from_utf8_lossy(bytes.as_ref());
        assert_eq!("FORBIDDEN", res);
    }
}

